# Can't Dockerize Elm

Tags: javascript, html, docker, functional-programming, elm

I've been having trouble dockerizing an Elm application. I have, as far as I can tell, created a complete and working Docker file ... but it doesn't work.

I'll explain.

So I have my scripts run in 3 files.

First is the start script `dockerBuild.sh`

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)

docker build -t elmapp .
docker run -p 8000:8000 elmapp
```

This just kills all previous docker image and builds and runs `elmapp`.

Next I have my `Dockerfile` that is being called:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn global add elm

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN chmod 777 runElm.sh

EXPOSE 8000
CMD sh runElm.sh
```

This produces the desired output and runs `runElm.sh`.

There are two alternative ways that I have the `runElm` file set up - they both produce the same result.

- Alternative 1

  `elm-reactor --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

This simply calls `elm-reactor` on the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="/_compile/src/Main.elm"></script>
  <style>
    body, html{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Alternative 2

Another possible way to compile an Elm app is to transpile the code to javascript and run the javascript in an html doc. Here the `runElm` file would be like this:

```
elm-make ./src/Main.elm --output=main.js
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

And the html would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Elm • Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
      body, html{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/main.js"></script>
  <script>
    var node = document.getElementById('main');
    var app = Elm.Main.embed(node);
  </script>

</html>
```

#### The problem:

The issue here is that when I navigate to localhost:8000 after my build queue is finished I get 404. However, if I run either of the two above alternatives *not* in a Dockerfile I get my program to compile just fine. Usually the problem is that ports are not properly exposed, but here I've exposed ports 8000 in my dockerfile, in my docker run, and it's the same port as is running on my `SimpleHTTPServer` and `elm-reactor` servers. I've looked at various other ways to get Docker to play nice with Elm and I've had difficulties.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

CLOSED - Not sure what I did, but after going through and making sure everything was formatted correctly it now works. Must have just been tired when I wrote the original code. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? elm is meant to be a front end framework anyway; you should compile elm rather than serve it in the reactor in production

Comment: Good question! I guess I might compile Elm in production but this is a toy app. I might run into the same problems later in the compiled version, but maybe its worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

if this is an httpserver i guess it should be running on port 80 ,when you specified the port 8000 that means you are exposing the container port not the host machine port,you can do port mapping in either ways

1. same way you did and like that the port 8000 on the container will be mapped
   to a random port on the host.
2. you can specify this by adding this the cmd which you use to create the
   container -p 8000:80 , 8000 on host machine, 80 on container

**NOTE**

The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that a certain port is to be exposed when a container is started:

> **EXPOSE port1 port2 …**

Even after exposing ports, while starting a container, you still need to provide port mapping using the -p flag to "docker run" cmd . This instruction is useful when you want to map your container exposed port to a custom host machine port

The port command looks up the public-facing port that is bound to an exposed
port in the container:

> **$ docker port CONTAINER PRIVATE_PORT**

if you want to know which is bound to container port run the following

> docker port **CONTAINER**

Comment: hmmm....I exposed port 8000 in my docker, I mapped 8000:8000 in dockerrun, and I have my server running on port 8000. It should be able to use port 8000 all the way down I think. Right?

Comment: yes the way you said it would expose port 8000 on your container and run it on port 8000 on you host machine .

Answer (score 1):

elm-reactor listens on localhost by default, not all interfaces.  This may prevent you from reaching it from outside the container,  try: `elm-reactor -a 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

If you get 404, that means the web server is running but it can't find the file you are requesting. So make sure your paths are correct, and check the output from your web server (`docker logs YOURCONTAINERNAME`)